# Proof that $u(0,0)=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm stuck with this boundary condition: $u(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2\times\sin(x_2)$. I don't think it is positive over the unit circle. How can I prove this?

> Let $B = \lbrace x = \left(x_1, x_2\right)\in\mathbb R^2:\vert x\vert < 1\rbrace$, and $u\in C^2(B)\cap C(\overline B)$ be the classical solution of the problem $$\begin{align}&\Delta u = 0\quad\text{in B},\\&u\left(x_1, x_2\right) = x_1^2\sin x_2\quad\text{on the boundary $\partial$B}.\end{align}$$ Prove that $$u(0, 0) = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Mean value property for harmonic functions.

Comment: Should I start like that u(x)=1/(|∂B(0,1)|) ∫_(∂B(0,1))▒〖y_1^2 siny_2 ds(y)〗

Comment: Professor Willie Wong

Comment: Yes, that's a good place to start.